# How to properly return and handle function errors

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I'm working on a WebApp using `PHP` and `Angular 4` to handle the `CRUD` operations on the application. However, when it comes to handling errors I fell like it's not the best way to do things.

This is how I'm calling the functions on the Angular:

```
createUser(user: any): any {
    return this._http.post(this.backendUrl, user).map(response => {
        console.log('Success message: ', response);
    }).catch(this.handleErrors);
}

handleErrors(error: Response): any {
    console.log('Handle error: ', error);
}
```

Let's say, for example, I want to create a new user with an unique email, so I have this `PHP` function to check if there is already an email registered:

```
$param = [':email' => $email];
$check = sql("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email", $param);
if ( $check ) {
    return print_r(array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'This email is already registered'
    ));
}

// [...Finish the user registration...]

return print_r(array(
    'success' => 1,
    'message' => 'Account successfully created!'
));
```

This way, when the function returns, I would check if the `success` value is either `1` or `0` and display the message using an `alert()`, for example. But I don't think this is the best/correct way to do this.

I tried to use the PHP exception, like this:

```
$param = [':email' => $email];
$check = sql("SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE email = :email", $param);
if ( $check ) {
    throw new Exception('This email is already registered');
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem. What happens is that it will throw an error if I check the function under the network tab on the console and the function will trigger the success return but with a null response. I see this message on the console.log:

> Success message: null

---

What would be the best way to handle this scenario? Where I want to check if the function is going to complete all the small pieces and return a success only when it actually do everything correctly.

Comment: I assume your `sql` function returns the result and not a bool. The other thing is that `print_r` returns a bool, you need a second parameter for string output like `print_r('foo', true)` lastly, why not return json? Lastly: do you even display some text? You should open it in a new tab. I don't now how you pull the data in PHP but if you pull with `$_REQUEST` you can just use get params to test the output

Comment: I don't know how PHP handles exceptions, but a response with the value `null`is weird. How long do you have to wait for that? Could it be a timeout?

Comment: @Soundz About the return from the sql function, it can be an Object, array or false, depending on the query. When I use the print_r method, there is no problem, everything works as expected, but I always need to check if the success return is actually a success or something was wrong within the function. I'd like to know if there is a way to use option to throw an error in this case, when something in the function is stopping it to continue.

Comment: @MarkusKollers there is problem with the timeout, on the localhost it returns within 20-40ms

Comment: So try my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RXJS-Catch will be triggered on HTTP-Codes, indicating an error. In general, it is recommended to send useful codes like 400 (Bad Request).

To send such an error, add the following line into your PHP error case:

```
http_response_code(400);
```

Now it should look like this:

```
if ( $check ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    return print_r(array(
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => 'This email is already registered'
    ));
}
```

Comment: It took me some time because I had to change some configurations on the Angular code in order to make it work. But it worked as I inteded. Thanks!